# Remove quotes from Factor variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have over 500 factor columns in my dataframe many of which are only "True"/"False". Is there any way to remove quotes for just these columns in one shot?

Example code --

```
sample=as.list(dataframe[1,])
for(i in 1:length(sample)){
 if(sample[i]=="false") sample[i]=false
}
```

The above code doesn't seem to work. Any leads appreciated!

Comment: I think you can just use `as.logical()`  There is a factor method

Comment: Indeed, but I want to remove quotes for those factor columns which have "true"/"false" and not from other columns. I have to convert this dataframe to a JSON...is it easier to remove quotes from JSON?

Comment: Then you will need to expand the question to include some sort of an example, please.

Comment: Try `data[columns] <- lapply(data[columns], as.logical)` where `columns` is the column names or indices of the ones you want converted

Comment: I am new to R and would like to know how do I select those specific columns? I tried using for and if and those conditions don't seem to work

Comment: If you want columns, say, 1, 2 , and 5 you would do `data[c(1, 2, 5)]`

Comment: Your code did not work because `false` does not represent anything. The logical value meaning false is noted: `FALSE` or more simply `F`. Also I don't think you want to take the first row but rather first column. Also there is no need for `as.list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves your problem:

```
> as.logical(c("true", "false", "True", "TRUE", "False"))
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

I was surprised too.

EDIT: I just noticed your code and I figured you could use a complete example.

Your data is in a data.frame (which is basically a list of columns). This is similar to a spreadsheet if you will.

Doing `dataframe[1,]` extracts the first line of your dataset. I guess what you want is rather to get the first column with `dataframe[,1]`. This column is a vector, which is good to operate on, no need to put it in a list.

So you would do:

```
as.logical(dataframe[,1])
```

But that would only *return* the data you want, not modify the dataframe! So you want to assign this result to the first column:

```
dataframe[,1] <- as.logical(dataframe[,1])
```

There you go, the first column no longer contains strings but logicals, no matter what the capitalization was.

If by any chance you actually meant to work on the row, this is unusual and likely means that you should transpose your data.frame, *i.e* swap rows and columns. This is done with `t`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. as.logical() did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 2):

If you give a better example (with some columns to convert, some columns not to convert), I'm happy to test. From your description, I think this will work:

```
data = lapply(data, FUN = function(x) {
    if (is.factor(x) & all(toupper(levels(x)) %in% c("TRUE", "FALSE"))) {
        return(as.logical(x))
    }
    return(x)
})
```

It tests if the column is a factor and if its levels can be coerced to TRUE and FALSE, converts it to logical if yes, returns the column unchanged if no.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want assuming that the columns you are talking about have two levels - "FALSE" and "TRUE".

```
df = data.frame(a=c("\"true\"","\"false\""), b=c("\"FALSE\"","\"TRUE\""), c=c("TRUE","FALSE"))
df
#        a       b     c
# 1  "true" "FALSE"  TRUE
# 2 "false"  "TRUE" FALSE

ftlev = c("\"FALSE\"", "\"TRUE\"")
df2 = lapply(df, FUN = function(x) {
  if (identical(ftlev,toupper(levels(x)))) {
    x = gsub('"','',x)
  }
  return(x)
})
as.data.frame(df2)
```

Output:

```
      a     b     c
1  true FALSE  TRUE
2 false  TRUE FALSE
```

The `as.logical()` function has been proposed in other answers/comments but it does not produce the expected output:

```
df2 = lapply(df, FUN = function(x) {
  if (identical(ftlev,toupper(levels(x)))) {
    x = as.logical(x)
  }
  return(x)
})
as.data.frame(df2)
```

Output:

```
  a  b     c
1 NA NA  TRUE
2 NA NA FALSE
```

Comment: Thank for the response @pcantqlupo. But I still see the quotes for true/false when I do str(df2) --

List of 3
 $ a: chr [1:2] "true" "false"
 $ b: chr [1:2] "FALSE" "TRUE"
 $ c: Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2 1

Comment: @outlier123 You are always going to see quotes around character data. For example run this: `str(data.frame(a=c("a","b")))` and compare that to the issue you are having: `str(data.frame(a=c("\"TRUE\"","\"FALSE\"")))`

Comment: I don't think there's any indication that OPs data actually have quotes inside the character strings, as in your test data.